# How to insert ordering data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

```
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 5  (render the cart for the user to view on the page)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$cartOutput = "";
$cartTotal = "";
$pp_checkout_btn = '';
$checkout_btn = '';
$product_id_array = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
} else {
    // Start PayPal Checkout Button
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/order_list.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartOutput" id="cartOutput" value = "<?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
    ';
    // Start the For Each loop
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1";     
$sql = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $details = $row["details"];
        }
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
        $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
        // Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly
        $x = $i + 1;
        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="' . $product_name . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="' . $price . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
        // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>RM ' . $price . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
        //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $pricetotal . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
        $i++; 
    } 
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
    $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);
    $cartTotal = "<div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart Total : ".$cartTotal." MYR</div>";
    // Finish the Paypal Checkout Btn
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">

    <input type="submit" type="button" name="submit">
    </form>';
}

?>
```

The above is the source code I learnt online to create a multidimensional array and submit to paypal for processing. Now I try to avoid paypal and wanna to insert the data submitted to my new database 'orders'. I created row (id (primary,auto increment),product_name,price,quantity,date_added) for this purpose but I failed to insert the data into it....

my attempt as below

```
<?php 
// This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
// Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
// http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
session_start(); // Start session first thing in script
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php"; 
?>
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) { 
$product_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($myConnection,$_POST[' . $product_name . ']);
$price=mysqli_real_escape_string($myConnection,$_POST[' . $price . ']);
$quantity=mysqli_real_escape_string($myConnection,$_POST[$each_item['quantity']]);
$date = date('d/m/Y', time());
$sqlCommand = ""INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price, quantity, date_added) VALUES('" . $_POST[$product_name] . "','" . $_POST[$price] . "','" . $_POST[$each_item['quantity']] . "', now())";      

$sql = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
$countArray = count($_SESSION["cart_array");
for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
$stmt->bind_param('ssd', $array[$product_name][$i], $array[$price][$i], $array[$each_item['quantity']][$i],$array[$date][$i]);
   $stmt->execute();
} 



echo $sql   ; 

exit();
}
?>
```

HELP~~~ I need to know what shall I put in if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) { in order to retrieve the date...i am really a beginner. I need some magic......

Comment: What are you trying to do with those string concatinators within a string? As I don't see anything sanitizing your data: Sanitize your data to prevent mysql injection. Does `$_POST[$product_name]` contain the value that has to be put into the product_name field of your row? In that case you can do that in a double-quotes string like so: `"some string {$_POST[$product_name]} some more string"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example use PDO but I think you get the idea, Also you should move to PDO or MYSQLI instead of mysql

the example:

```
<?php
// pdo example

$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (:value1, :value2, :value3)';

// $dbh is pdo connection
$insertTable = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$countArray = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
   $insertTable->bindParam(':value1', $array['value1'][$i], PDO::PARAM_INT); // if value is int
   $insertTable->bindParam(':value2', $array['value2'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR); // if value is str
   $insertTable->bindParam(':value3', $array['value3'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $insertTable->execute();
}

?>
```

**Input name format**

I see you are doing this: `amount_' . $x . '` your array post will look like this:

```
[amount_0] => 100
[amount_1] => 200
[amount_2] => 1
[quantity] => 10
[quantity] => 20
[quantity] => 1
```

but if your write `amount[]` the array will look like this:

```
[amount] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100
        [1] => 200
        [2] => 1
    )

[quantity] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 20
        [2] => 1
```

The last option makes it much better to read the array.

**MYSQLI example**

```
<?php
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 

$countArray = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
$stmt->bind_param('ssd', $array['value1'][$i], $array['value2'][$i], $array['value3'][$i]);
   $stmt->execute();
} 
?>
```

As you can see there is standing `ssd` before the parameters these are the types there are 4 types:

- i = intenger
- s = string
- d = double
- b = blob

You must always define this.

**Edit**

You should use this:

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) { 

$sql= 'INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price, quantity, date_added) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())';      

$stmt = $myConnection->prepare($sql); 
$countArray = count($_POST["item_name");
for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['item_name'][$i], $_POST['amount'][$i], $_POST['quantity'][$i]);
$stmt->execute();
}

echo $sql   ; 

exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: can you set an example using mysqli?

Comment: I have tried to edited accordingly but still no luck...it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/u382560552/public_html/order_list.php on line 14

Comment: I just wondering if it is correct to put if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) { to retrieve the posted data?

Comment: Can you show line 14? For your last question no, you only check now if the variable exist. Every time you need a value of the post you have to use `$_POST['name']` you van Also make a variable with the post data like this: `$name = $_POST['cartOutput'];`

Comment: Your problem is the query instead of the post you should use ? For the data you want to insert see my exemple above. Also `count($array); should be something else.

Comment: my line 14 is exactly this  if (isset($_POST['cartOutput']))

Comment: Please see the my above edited version but still no luck..i need some light please

Comment: See my Edit in the answer

Comment: THanks Perry, IT WORKS MAGICALLY...I have spent the whole day thinking about this thing really...and now I got progress...there is new problem...let's say I got select to item, after i pressed submit order, i checked my table, only 1 item got inserted into, any pro advice on how ppl do the table for collecting orders? your help much appreciated

Comment: Hi Perry, the value doesn't add correctly?...seem like missing something

Comment: it is like the top item doens't add into the table...and the quantity shifted..i will study more tomorrow..thanks mate

Comment: i have posted a new question...if you could help would be much appreciated 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936460/minor-error-when-insert-data-to-mysql-from-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 0):

1) Your form action for pp_checkout_btn still shows "paypal web". I think that's just a typo, so please go ahead and change that first.

2) Moreover, your insert statement can use a little tweaks. Please provide results for the following two statements, for framing an exact insert statement:

```
print_r($_POST) // once the data has been posted
echo $sql // place this just before calling exit
```

-- seekers01

Comment: where should i put print_r($_POST)?

Comment: Just before:
    `code`if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) {`code`
inside php tag

Comment: exactly my point ... there is issue with your form_submit.. the post variable itself is not getting initialized.
please paste a copy of order_list.php

Answer (score 0):

I think your insert code should be as below
`$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price, quantity, date_added) VALUES('" . $_POST[$product_name] . "','" . $_POST[$price] . "','" . $_POST[$each_item['quantity']] . "', now())") or die (mysql_error());`

Edit:
Also, the statement inside `for` loop should be
`$stmt->bind_param('ssd', $array[$product_name][$i], $array[$price][$i], $array[$each_item['quantity']][$i]);`

Comment: tried no luck..the issue is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/u382560552/public_html/order_list.php on line 14

Comment: as above the line 14 is if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) {

Comment: There should be a semicolon after `echo $sql`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you should refer to:

```
<?php 
// This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
// Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
// http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
session_start(); // Start session first thing in script
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php"; 
?>
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) {
    $product_name=$_POST[$product_name];
    $price=$_POST[$price];
    $quantity=$_POST[$each_item['quantity']];
    $sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price, quantity, date_added) VALUES('" . $_POST[$product_name] . "','" . $_POST[$price] . "','" . $_POST[$each_item['quantity']] . "', now())";       

    $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
    $countArray = count($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssd', $array[$product_name][$i], $array[$price][$i], $array[$each_item['quantity']][$i]);
       $stmt->execute();
    } 

    echo $sql;

    exit();
}
?>
```

To retrieve the date:

```
$date = date('d/m/Y', time());
```

Try this and then see if it works.

Comment: same error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/u382560552/public_html/order_list.php on line 14