# Minor Error when insert data to mysql from multidimensional array

Tags: php, database, multidimensional-array, insert, mysqli

```
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 5  (render the cart for the user to view on the page)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$cartOutput = "";
$cartTotal = "";
$pp_checkout_btn = '';
$checkout_btn = '';
$product_id_array = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
} else {
    // Start PayPal Checkout Button
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/order_list.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartOutput" id="cartOutput" value = "<?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
    ';
    // Start the For Each loop
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1";     
$sql = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $details = $row["details"];
        }
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
        $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
        // Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly
        $x = $i + 1;
        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="' . $product_name . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="' . $price . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
        // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>RM ' . $price . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
        //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $pricetotal . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
        $i++; 
    } 
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
    $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);
    $cartTotal = "<div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart Total : ".$cartTotal." MYR</div>";
    // Finish the Paypal Checkout Btn
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">

    <input type="submit" type="button" name="submit">
    </form>';
}

?>
```

This the above is the multidimensional array that grab the variable from mySQL database and the below try to insert the data into the new database i created named "orders"

```
<?php 
// This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
// Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
// http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
session_start(); // Start session first thing in script
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php"; 
?>


<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) { 

$sql= 'INSERT INTO orders (product_name,  quantity,price, date_added) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())';      

$stmt = $myConnection->prepare($sql); 

$countArray = count($_POST['item_name']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['item_name'][$i], $_POST['quantity'][$i], $_POST['amount'][$i]);
$stmt->execute();
}

echo $sql   ; 

exit();
}
?>
```

the above code success to insert data into orders table (credit to Perry) but, it miss up the top item eg in my cart show:

item1 egg, $1.00 2QTY
item2 chicken,$30,1QTY

after i clicked submit, in my sql table showns only item2 chicken but with $1.00 and 2QTY which should belong to item 1 egg. how should i fix this? i tried changing the $i to '-1','1' both still not working. Thanks

```
Notice: Undefined index: item_name in /home/u382560552/public_html/order_list.php on line 22
INSERT INTO orders (product_name, quantity,price, date_added) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())
```

this is what pop out if only one item selected and submit

Comment: can you show your POST? Use this code : `echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';` and post it here :)

Answer (score 0):

if you says it is a multidimensional array you should write your code like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
for ($j=0; &j < $countArray ; $j++){
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['item_name'][$i,$j], $_POST['quantity'][$i,$j], $_POST['amount'][$i,&j]);
$stmt->execute();
```

}
    }

now this will display an tow dimensional array 
for three dimensional array use a third variable

Comment: tried but it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']' in /home/u382560552/public_html/order_list.php on line 27

Comment: i fixed that error but it eventually appear fatal error with your code

Comment: are you sure the array is multidimensional and how many dimensions there is?

Comment: how do i know the number of dimensions? I thought the code above can tell the story..basically i got a products table and the top code retrieve data from product table to show the product name, price and quantity, then i create a submit button below in order for customer to press the submit button and post the data into my orders table..

Comment: im sorry i cant help but try to access your database to see if the information is stored in the order you wanted that may help you know in which part of the code is the problem

Comment: i pretty sure it is in order but only as mentioned above
the above code success to insert data into orders table (credit to Perry) but, it miss up the top item eg in my cart show:

item1 egg, $1.00 2QTY item2 chicken,$30,1QTY

after i clicked submit, in my sql table showns only item2 chicken but with $1.00 and 2QTY which should belong to item 1 egg. how should i fix this? i tried changing the $i to '-1','1' both still not working. Thanks

Comment: only when inserting data it skipped the product name...and other shifted upward..otherwise all good

Comment: only when inserting data it skipped the product name at the first line...and other shifted upward..otherwise all good