# Insert Multidimensional array into Mysql Table

Tags: mysql, pdo, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
TAB = Array ( 
    [field1] => Array ( [0] => 111 [1] => 777 [2] => 222 ... ) 
    [field2] => Array ( [0] => MAT [1] => MAT [2] => MAT ... ) 
    [field3] => Array ( [0] => 8A [1] => 8B [2] => 8C ... )
    )
```

I want INSERT the values of this Array to the mysql temporary TABLE1, with PDO.
How can I to do?
Thanks.

Comment: What language do you going to use for this?

Comment: The answer is in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17920768/4347038

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ASSUMING PHP and ASSUMING you have a TABLE1 which has two location columns and one value column (one column for the location in the first array, the second for the location in the second array and the value column for the actual value).
$dbh is your database handler.

```
$keys = array_keys($TAB); // because the array is associative, we need array_keys
for ($i = 0; $i < $TAB.length; $i++){ 
    for ($j = 0; $j < $TAB[keys[$i]].length; $j++){
           $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE1 (location1, location2, value)  VALUES (:location1, :location2, :value )");
           $stmt->bindParam(':location1', $i);
           $stmt->bindParam(':location2', $j);
           $stmt->bindParam(':value', $TAB[$keys[$i]][$j]);
           $stmt->execute();
        }
}
```